# A running windows service downloading binary-blocked by antivirus

Tags: windows, installation, updates, installer

I have a running winservice which downloads an exe to disk and runs the logic from that binary.

Everytime I download ,right before the file is saved to the filesystem, I have the AVG antivirus prompting the user to verify if it can run it or move it to vault.

I even tried download a DAT file to test , ran into the same issue.

I would be running it on servers where there wont be any user intervention. How can I get around this ?

Firefox/Windows autoupdater for instance,seems to autoupgrade seemlessly even with the antivirus installed. How does it work ?

Does getting whitelisted the only way around this ? I cant edit AVG settings since its a client machine.

Thanks,

KG

Comment: Use a different antivirus, or whitelist the EXE.

Comment: The problem could be related to the content of the downloaded executable.  Giving it a digital signature, for example, might help.